# Ubuntu 15 Bash Screen Scripting

Tags: screen

I'd like to edit my bashrc or do something with a similarly automatic result to make my terminal execute Ctrl^A, Tab, Ctrl^A, C everytime I split the terminal (Ctrl^A, Shift^S).

basically I'd like to automate screen's behavior some because having a two part keystroke for splitting THEN another for switching to THEN another for starting up bash in this window seems to me like something that should be ONE keystroke.

as a matter of fact if Ctrl^A where enough on it's own to do all this, that would be phenomenal.

I've already configured my bash to start screen on a normal basis as per :
[How can I start Linux screen automatically when I open a new terminal window?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675139/how-can-i-start-linux-screen-automatically-when-i-open-a-new-terminal-window)